# Scan for BLE devices and present them in an UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, class, bluetooth-lowenergy, instance-variables

I try to find a way to scan for BLE devices and present them in an UITableView. The scan, connect, read and write functionality for BLE devices is clear and works! So my questions are focused on the interaction between the 'ScanTableView' and 'BletoothManager' class.

**These are my two classes:**

```
//  ScanTableView.swift

import UIKit

class ScanTableView: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scanTableView: UITableView!

    var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager?()
    var tableViewScanTime = 5
    var timer1: NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let _ = bluetoothManager?.peripheralArray.count {
            return bluetoothManager!.peripheralArray.count
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = scanTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanCell",forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = bluetoothManager!.peripheralArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = bluetoothManager!.peripheralArray[indexPath.row].RSSI
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        bluetoothManager!.selectedPeripheral = bluetoothManager!.peripheralArray[indexPath.row]
        bluetoothManager!.connectPeripheral(bluetoothManager!.selectedPeripheral!)
    }

    func refresh() {
        scanTableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        timer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "scanTableViewRefresh", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
    }

    func scanTableViewRefresh() {
        scanTableView.reloadData()
        tableViewScanTime--

        if tableViewScanTime <= 0 {
            timer1.invalidate()
            bluetoothManager!.CBmanager.stopScan()
            print("StopScan")
            tableViewScanTime = 5
            bluetoothManager!.peripheralArray.sortInPlace({$0.RSSI < $1.RSSI})
            self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
            self.scanTableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//  BluetoothManager.swift

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    struct BluetoothPeripheral {
        let name: String
        let UUID: String
        let RSSI: String
        let peripheral: CBPeripheral

        init(name: String, UUID: String, RSSI: NSNumber, peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            self.name = "\(name)"
            self.UUID = "\(UUID)"
            self.RSSI = "\(RSSI)"
            self.peripheral = peripheral
        }
    }

    let DEVICE_NAME:String! = "TEST"

    //Creat an instance of ScanTableView Class
    var scanTableView: ScanTableView()


    var peripheralArray: [BluetoothPeripheral] = []
    var selectedPeripheral: BluetoothPeripheral?
    var characteristicArray: [CBCharacteristic] = []
    var CBmanager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var measurementValue: [[AnyObject?]] = [[]]

    //Basic functions
    override init() {
        super.init()
        CBmanager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func connectPeripheral(selectedPeripheral: BluetoothPeripheral) {
        CBmanager.connectPeripheral(selectedPeripheral.peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func disconnectPeripheral(selectedPeripheral: BluetoothPeripheral) {
        for characteristic in characteristicArray {
            selectedPeripheral.peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
        }
        CBmanager.cancelPeripheralConnection(selectedPeripheral.peripheral)
    }

    func ScanForPeripherals() {
        CBmanager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        print("Scanning")
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch(central.state) {
        case .PoweredOn:
            CBmanager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
            print("scan")
        case .PoweredOff, .Resetting, .Unauthorized, .Unsupported, .Unknown:
            peripheralArray.removeAll()

            //This invokes an exception
            //scanTableView.scanTableView.reloadData()

            print("NO BLE!")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let UUID = "\(peripheral.identifier)".substringFromIndex("\(peripheral.identifier)".startIndex.advancedBy(31))
        if let peripheralName = peripheral.name {
            if peripheralName.containsString(DEVICE_NAME) {
                peripheralArray.append(BluetoothPeripheral(name: peripheral.name!, UUID: UUID, RSSI: RSSI, peripheral: peripheral))
                print(peripheralArray)
            }
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected")
        measurementValue.removeAll()
        peripheral.delegate = self
        selectedPeripheral!.peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("Fail")
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("Restore")
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("Disconnected")
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
        for characteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!{
            if characteristic.properties.contains(CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify) {
                peripheral.discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic(characteristic)
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        if characteristic.isNotifying {
            characteristicArray.append(characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
            peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(characteristic)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        //Store new characteristic values
    }
}
```

**Now my questions:**

The shown code works but I'm not able to interact between the two classes.
For example I would like to reload my opened ScanTableView from my BluetoothManager class. That's not possible... every time when I try this, I get an exception that I would unwrap an optional. Why? Are there any differences between 'normal' classes and the classes shown in the GUI (UITableView, UIView...)? I documented the exception line...

It would be really nice, if anyone could explain me what to do in such situations :).

**I'm happy for any suggestions or improvements!**

Comment: Can you indicate which line is giving you the error? Rather than using an NSTimer it would be better to either set your table view controller as a delegate for your Bluetooth manager and create a protocol so that the Bluetooth manager can advise the tableview controller about newly discovered devices or have the Bluetooth manager use NSNotification to advise interested classes about changes

Comment: In the middle of the second class, I commented 'scanTableView.scanTableView.reloadData()' out. This part invokes an exception. I would like to use the NSTimer module, to "control" how long I search for any devices. So in this case I just search for 5 seconds. I don't want to use the NSNotification module, to avoid confusing code... I think, I have got an issue with the right instance of my ScanTableView. I tried it with 'storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scanTableViewIdentifier") as! ScanTableView' but without any success.

Comment: If you don't want to use NSNotification then you will need to use a protocol and delegation.  Your Bluetooth manager can't instantiate a new instance of ScanTableView, it needs to communicate with the one that already exists and this would be by that view controller setting itself as the bluetooth manager's delegate

Comment: Okay, I will give my best to implement that and post my question or solution :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @paulw11 said, I had to creat a delegate protocol:

```
protocol BluetoothDelegate: class {

    func ReloadView()
}
```

This 'ReloadView' method is declared in my ScanTableView class:

```
func ReloadView() {
    scanTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now, I had to do some additional:

1. Add the BluetoothDelegate to ScanTableView class
2. Declare a variable 'weak var delegate: BluetoothDelegate?' in BluetoothManager class
3. call the delegate method with 'delegate?.ReloadView()' at the wished point in BluetoothManager class
4. Activate the delegate in ScanTableView by using 'bluetoothManager?.delegate = self'

That's it!