# Perform an action when a bluetooth device connects or disconnects on CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am in process of making an app where, where when the first time app is launched the user enter the device they want to connect. Once connected, the user leaves/closes the app.

Now every time that same bluetooth device is connected or disconnected, I want a function to be called in the app. How can I achieve this?

I am using Corebluetooth currently to get names of devices etc. but cannot find a way to achieve this. Any suggestions? TIA!

Comment: Connecting to a BTLE device is a kind of verbose process. Scan, connect, discovery of services, discovery of characteristics. Please add what have done, improve your answer by posting code. Probably you should look in `CBPeripheralDelegate` protocol

Comment: @andrea so the connection to the device is done automatically like a normal iPhone does. The user device would already be paired. As soon as they turn it on it connects automatically just like it does normally. The app itself takes the name of their device from the user, uses a cbmanager to scan Bluetooth devices and if the name matches the users input name, it saves it in a variable. Now i want to track when this specific device is connected or disconnected again, in the background, and call a function every time it happens.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379136/scan-for-ble-devices-and-present-them-in-an-uitableview

Comment: Start with a simple scan, connect, disconnect routine. After that you will probably know how to search for a specific device, connect to it and call a delegate func or something like that

Comment: all that i know, i need to know how to have a function call when the app is in the background and the device reconnects / disconnects